# unexpected token <

Tags: node.js, faye

Using the nodejs v.6.7 with faye v.7.1 I am getting error

```
/path/livestats/node_modules/faye0.7/faye.js:18
  ID_LENGTH:        <%= Faye::ID_LENGTH %>,
                    ^
-----------------------
Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Module._compile (module.js:427:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/livestats/lib/livestats.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
-----------------------
```

I am trying to implement example showing in peepcode's Meet node.js video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you requiring `faye.js` as is before building `faye_node`.

You need to follow [instructions on faye repository](https://github.com/faye/faye/blob/master/README.rdoc) or installing it via `npm`:

```
npm install faye -d
```

If you install it via NPM you can `require("faye-node")`